# How to make Text Body in VB <b> not working

Tags: vba, fonts

I have a code to send email from excel. All the info is taken from cells. I am trying to make "J4" bold but it says symtex error when I use . Sorry i'm pretty new to VBA so please explain as if i'm a complete noob.
Code is:

```
Sub SendMassEmail()

    Row_Number = 1

    Do
        DoEvents
        Row_Number = Row_Number + 1
        Dim Mail_Body_Message As String
        Dim Full_Name As String
        Dim Twitter_Code As String


        Mail_Body_Message = Sheet1.Range("J2") & vbNewLine & Sheet1.Range("J3") & vbNewLine & Sheet1.Range("J4") & vbNewLine & Sheet1.Range("J5") & vbNewLine & Sheet1.Range("J6")

        Full_Name = Sheet1.Range("B" & Row_Number)
        Twitter_Code = Sheet1.Range("D" & Row_Number)

        Mail_Body_Message = Replace(Mail_Body_Message, "replace_name_here", Full_Name)
        Mail_Body_Message = Replace(Mail_Body_Message, "promo_code_replace", Twitter_Code)
        MsgBox Mail_Body_Message


        Call SendTheEmail(Sheet1.Range("A" & Row_Number), "This is the Subject", Mail_Body_Message)

    Loop Until Row_Number = 5

    MsgBox "**Emails Sent**"




End Sub
```

Comment: Also, if you are able to tell me how to change font colour that would be amazing! I need the use either RGB(49,112,35) OR #317023. I tried Range.("J2").Font.Color = RBG(49,112,35)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the variable Mail_Body_Message is just text. There is no way to indicate when something is bold or a color. You must use HTML in your email to achieve what you want. For example:

Replace

```
Mail_Body_Message = Sheet1.Range("J2") & vbNewLine & Sheet1.Range("J3") & vbNewLine & Sheet1.Range("J4") & vbNewLine & Sheet1.Range("J5") & vbNewLine & Sheet1.Range("J6")
```

With

```
Mail_Body_Message = "<HTML><BODY><font size=3>" & Sheet1.Range("J2") & vbNewLine & Sheet1.Range("J3") & vbNewLine & "<b>" & Sheet1.Range("J4") & "</b>" & vbNewLine & Sheet1.Range("J5") & vbNewLine & Sheet1.Range("J6") & "</font></BODY></HTML>"
```

There is some more work you need to do. You must set your mail item's body format to **olFormatHTML**. You must also set the HTMLBody of the message to your variable. Basically, you'll need something like this:

```
Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With MItem
    .To = EmailAddr
    .Subject = Subj
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .HTMLBody = Mail_Body_Message
    .Send
End With
```

You can also change the color of text with HTML font tags. For example:

```
Mail_Body_Message = "<font color='red'>" & VBAVariable & "</font>"
```

Comment: I have done what you said but it says compile Error: expected: expression and highlights the = < part of it.
Mail_Body_Message = <HTML><B
Is there a way of asking vba to tell me what is wrong with the expression? Like a debug sort of thing?

Comment: Mail_Body_Message is still a string. You need quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate it. There was a slight spelling error in the Sub line so it wasn't doing what you said it would but found that after some playing and investigation. 

Thanks for you help and thank you for explaining why i had to do it and why mine didn't work instead of just giving me the code.