# Embolden text and red font within emails

Tags: vba, excel, html-email

I have code (below) that works perfectly as part of a larger VBA code. However I would like to highlight some of the text bold and one line red and am unsure how.

How I would like the email to look:

[image]

```
.body = "Hello" & Chr(13) & Chr(13) _
& "The attached PICS and Benefits have been flagged as impacting your business or finance area. As such, these will require your approval before being presented to the funding board as part of the project investment board submission." & Chr(13) & Chr(13) _
& "1) Project Accountants: " & Chr(13) _
& "If you approve of the attached PICS and Benefits, please respond to this email stat[![enter image description here][1]][1]ing your approval, CC the FBS Projects Team and forward on this email to the relevant BAU (L4) Business Approver. Should you wish to query or revise the attached view, please liaise with your relevant FBS contact." & Chr(13) & Chr(13) _
& "2)  BAU Business Approvers: " & Chr(13) _
& " If you approve of the attached PICS and Benefits, please respond to this email stating your approval, CC the FBS Projects Team and the Project Accountant (accountant stated on the attached).Should you wish to query or revise the attached view, please liaise with the relevant Project Accountant." & Chr(13) & Chr(13) _
& "3)  BAU Finance Approvers: " & Chr(13) _
& "If you approve of the attached PICS and Benefits, please respond to this email stating your approval, CC the FBS Projects Team and the Project Accountant (accountant stated on the attached). Should you wish to query or revise the attached view, please liaise with the relevant Project Accountant." & Chr(13) & Chr(13) _
& "***Please ensure the email thread is continued to maintain the audit trail***" & Chr(13) & Chr(13) _
& "Kind regards,"
```

Comment: See my answer in this question, it's very similar and easy to follow [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373280/how-to-make-text-body-in-vb-b-not-working/33373866#33373866). Basically, you'll need html and not plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to use HTML formatting to have Bold text and to change color of text. You can edit formatting, to look exactly as you want ..

```
.HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:Arial;font-size:12'>" & _
"Hello<br><br>" & _
"The attached PICS and Benefits have been flagged as impacting your business or finance area. As such, these will require your approval before being presented to the funding board as part of the project investment board submission.<br><br>" & _
"<B>1) Project Accountants:</B><br>" & _
"If you approve of the attached PICS and Benefits, please respond to this email stat[![enter image description here][1]][1]ing your approval, CC the FBS Projects Team and forward on this email to the relevant BAU (L4) Business Approver. Should you wish to query or revise the attached view, please liaise with your relevant FBS contact.<br><br>" & _
"<B>2)  BAU Business Approvers:</B><br>" & _
"If you approve of the attached PICS and Benefits, please respond to this email stating your approval, CC the FBS Projects Team and the Project Accountant (accountant stated on the attached).Should you wish to query or revise the attached view, please liaise with the relevant Project Accountant.<br><br>" & _
"<B>3)  BAU Finance Approvers:</B><br>" & _
"If you approve of the attached PICS and Benefits, please respond to this email stating your approval, CC the FBS Projects Team and the Project Accountant (accountant stated on the attached). Should you wish to query or revise the attached view, please liaise with the relevant Project Accountant.<br><br>" & _
"<font color=""red"">***Please ensure the email thread is continued to maintain the audit trail***</font><br><br>" & _
"Kind regards,</p>"
```